# Convert double to long without truncating

Tags: c#

How to convert a double to a long without truncating it?

For example,

I want -26.3999745 to become -263999745

So far the methods I have tried such as `Convert.ToInt64()` truncate the number.

EDIT:
The number of decimal places varies, some of the numbers may have 5 decimal places

Comment: It's not the same number, what criteria do you have for this conversion?

Comment: Just multiply by 100000 for example. Or convert so string and remove the decimal-character.

Comment: e.g.: `long.Parse((-26.3999745).ToString().Replace(".",""))`

Comment: I would suggest writing this into `string` or just keep it in `double`. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: In what way is this conversion meaningful, if (I assume) `-2.63999745` would be converted into exactly the same long value. "Truncation" may not be occurring, but it's definitely losing information.

Comment: I agree with Damien. This seems nonsensical. 1.0001, 10.001, 100.01, 1000.1 and 10001 would all produce the same result. In what way could this be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are really sure this is what you really want ..

```
long.Parse((-26.3999745).ToString().Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.ToString(), string.Empty)))
```

Comment: Could be coincidence, but I was thinking the same

Comment: It's usually better to use `String.Empty` instead of `""`

Comment: @KamilT Really? **That** is what bothers you about this approach? Not that the `"."` should be a culture-independent decimal separator or that the whole thing is useless?

Comment: I don't like using `string.Empty` - it's harder to read than `""` IMO. But YMMV!

Comment: it won't work if it is  "-26,3999745"  (depends on current culture)

Comment: this will not work always. because you must always have `7` decimal places

Answer (score 3):

Following 2 steps

1. Get the numbers after the decimal `n`
2. Multiply by `10^n`

Code:

```
double number = -26.3999745;
int n = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits((decimal)number)[3])[2];
long result = (long)(number * Math.Pow(10, n));
```

If you like to follow Single Responsibility (you should), then you can go with a second approach that is also not culture specific:

```
static int GetCountAfterDecimal(double number)
{
    int count = 0;

    string seperator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                                            .NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

    string numberAsString = number.ToString();
    int indexOfSeperator = numberAsString.IndexOf(seperator);

    if (indexOfSeperator >= 0)
        count = numberAsString.Length - indexOfSeperator - 1;

    return count;
}

static long RemoveDecimalPoint(double number, int numbersCountAfterDecimal)
{
    return (long)(number * Math.Pow(10, numbersCountAfterDecimal));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double number = -26.3999745;
    long result = RemoveDecimalPoint(number, GetCountAfterDecimal(number));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
double YourNumber = -26.3999745;
int DecimalPlacesCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(Convert.ToDecimal(YourNumber))[3])[2];
long number = Convert.ToInt64("1".PadRight(DecimalPlacesCount + 1, '0'));
long kajs = (long) (YourNumber * number);
```